# intellij - keymap / hotkey / shortcut per module / project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have many projects

I use a hotkey to deploy files built externally to my deploy folder, as intellij is not doing that or is doing that very very unreliably and slowly.

so say in project A I have a shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to deploy all files I need to the deploy folder with a shell script. In Project B I have a different shell script (obviously) to deploy all I need. But I dont want to create a new shortcut, I want to reuse <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but that doesn't seem to work

Is there a way to define a shortcut / hotkey on module basis? or a different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment, you can set several different keyboard layouts and switch them manually. Also there is a feature request to provide project level keymap: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127090

Comment: actually what I did and _seems_ to work across projects, is using a simple ant build file per project, with the same target in each, just different directories. That _seems_ to work. I will add an answer for completeness

Answer (score 0):

I just use always the similar ant build file in all projects doing a simple copy, and assign the shortcut to that ant build file:

so in each project I have a `build.xml` in the root with this content

I guess it works because the "target name" is always the same in each build.xml

```
<project name="joomlaPHC" default="copy-css" basedir=".">
    <target name="copy-css"
            description="copies css files" >
        <copydir src="/home/myuser/IdeaProjects/MYPROJECT/src/public" dest="/var/www/html/MYPROJECT.local/public"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

the shortcut seems to work
[image]

[image]
don't forget to assign the jdk

hope it helps